# Having 2 identities in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity

I need to have some how 2 identity columns in one table. One that is normal identity and another one that will reset yearly.

I have done the reset part with the help of `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TestTable', RESEED, 0)` in the insert procedure.

But I don't know how to have a normal identity besides this one. Solution may be using two tables but I prefer to have both of them in a single table.

Comment: You can't have 2 columns with identity property (I assume SQL Server). Which version are you on? You might be able to use sequences if you are in a new version. See this related question: ['Id' with the format: YYYYNNNNNN with the NNNNNN part restarting each year](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135032/id-with-the-format-yyyynnnnnn-with-the-nnnnnn-part-restarting-each-year/135034#135034)

Comment: the sql version is 2012

Comment: Consider using a `SEQUENCE` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110)),  The next value can be reset using `ALTER SEQUENCE...RESTART WITH`.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136220/why-can-a-sql-server-table-not-have-more-than-one-identity-column

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the comments may have answered this for you, but so there's an actual answer:

You cannot have two columns in one table that both have an `IDENTITY(n,m)` specification.

The most sensible approach for your requirement is probably:

- your normal always-incrementing identity column should have the `IDENTITY` specification
- use a `SEQUENCE` ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110)) for reference documentation and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058(v=sql.110)) for more general guidance) to control the other column that should reset each year.

You can restart a sequence on demand using

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence_name> RESTART WITH <new_start_value>;
```

This command could be issued in a number of ways, for example from a job scheduled to run yearly on your desired reset date.